# TWTRComposer dismisses automatically within 15 seconds

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, twtrcomposer

I am using the the latest Twitter 2.4.0 provided by Fabric. The TWTRComposer dismisses automatically within 15 seconds after being presented, with the following log in the console:

```
[1598:207673] plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post interrupted
[1598:207084] plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated
[1598:206158] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
[1598:206158] Tweet composition cancelled.
```

This is how the TWTRComposer is presented:

```
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
[composer setText:trimmedText];
[composer setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://movies.ndtv.com/bollywood/shah-rukh-khan-is-prisma-perfect-see-what-he-shared-on-instagram-1440933"]];

            [composer showFromViewController:APP_DELEGATE.viewController completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
                NSString *msg,*msgTitle;
                if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");

                }
            }];
```

Note: The tweet view does not populate any preview image, when this happens.